# Why does jQPlot dateAxisRenderer not working correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqplot

i would like to use the jQPlot and will render an axis as a series of date values - the raw package of jQPlot can be font here:

http://www.jqplot.com/

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js.html

**The Problem is this:**

a) xaxis don't start at the left side and also it will show values that i don't want to see

b) just the same problem on the right with more numbers that dont need

c) i would like to have all days on the xaxis 1 2 3 4 5 ... not 31 3 6 9 ...

d) is it possible to set a kind of offset to the bottom (just a little bit ...)

**Screenshot:**
[image: Picture from current status]

**My Code:**

```
$.jqplot('chartdiv', [
    [
        ['2012-08-01', 0],
        ['2012-08-02', 0],
        ['2012-08-03', 0],
        ['2012-08-04', 0],
        ['2012-08-05', 0],
        ['2012-08-06', 0],
        ['2012-08-07', 1],
        ['2012-08-08', 0],
        ['2012-08-09', 6],
        ['2012-08-10', 0],
        ['2012-08-11', 0],
        ['2012-08-12', 0],
        ['2012-08-13', 0],
        ['2012-08-14', 0],
        ['2012-08-15', 0],
        ['2012-08-16', 0],
        ['2012-08-17', 0],
        ['2012-08-18', 0],
        ['2012-08-19', 0],
        ['2012-08-20', 0],
        ['2012-08-21', 0],
        ['2012-08-22', 0],
        ['2012-08-23', 0],
        ['2012-08-24', 0],
        ['2012-08-25', 0],
        ['2012-08-26', 0],
        ['2012-08-27', 0],
        ['2012-08-28', 0],
        ['2012-08-29', 0],
        ['2012-08-30', 0],
        ['2012-08-31', 0]
    ]
], {
    title: 'Downloadstatistik',
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions: {
                formatString: '%#d',
                tickInterval: '1 month'
            },
            pad: 1.0
        },
        yaxis: {
            tickOptions: {
                formatString: '%.0f'
            },
            min: 0
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To start, you should try to set your tickInterval to "1 day" :)

After this, the trick is to set your xaxis min and max according to first and last values of your dates array.

Here's an example :

```
var timeline = [[
    ['2012-08-01', 0], ['2012-08-02', 0], ['2012-08-03', 0],
    ['2012-08-04', 0], ['2012-08-05', 0], ['2012-08-06', 0],
    ['2012-08-07', 1], ['2012-08-08', 0], ['2012-08-09', 6],
    ['2012-08-10', 0], ['2012-08-11', 0], ['2012-08-12', 0],
    ['2012-08-13', 0], ['2012-08-14', 0], ['2012-08-15', 0],
    ['2012-08-16', 0], ['2012-08-17', 0], ['2012-08-18', 0],
    ['2012-08-19', 0], ['2012-08-20', 0], ['2012-08-21', 0],
    ['2012-08-22', 0], ['2012-08-23', 0], ['2012-08-24', 0],
    ['2012-08-25', 0], ['2012-08-26', 0], ['2012-08-27', 0],
    ['2012-08-28', 0], ['2012-08-29', 0], ['2012-08-30', 0],
    ['2012-08-31', 0]
]];
var plot = $.jqplot('chartdiv', timeline, {
    title: 'Downloadstatistik',
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions: { formatString: '%#d' },
            tickInterval: '1 day',
            min: timeline[0][0][0],
            max: timeline[0][timeline[0].length-1][0]
        },
        yaxis: {
            tickOptions: { formatString: '%.0f' },
            min: 0
        }
    }
});
```

Also I think no pad is needed.

**Edit (new jsFiddle added):**

You can test this sample code here : http://jsfiddle.net/JhHPz/4/

Comment: Well ok this works. But in the bottom line (xaxis jqplot doesn't show all days as number 1 ,3 ,6 ,9 instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6 ... the "dots" from data are marked ...

Comment: Sorry, I surely miss-click when copy/paste the jsFiddle link.
I've updated my answer with a new one.
Also, what do you mean when you say :
``the "dots" from data are marked`` ?