# jQplot Date axis chart starting point

Tags: javascript, graph, jqplot

I dont seem to be able to get my chart to start on the first date the plot data and finishes on the last one.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  var line1=[['01-Nov-12',18],['02-Nov-12',18],['03-Nov-12',18],['04-Nov-12',18],['05-Nov-12',18],['06-Nov-12',18],['07-Nov-12',18],['08-Nov-12',18],['09-Nov-12',18],['10-Nov-12',18],['12-Nov-12',0],['13-Nov-12',0],['14-Nov-12',0],['15-Nov-12',0],['16-Nov-12',0],['17-Nov-12',0],['18-Nov-12',0],['19-Nov-12',0],['20-Nov-12',0],['21-Nov-12',0],['22-Nov-12',0],['23-Nov-12',0],['24-Nov-12',0]];

  var line2=[['01-Nov-12',20],['02-Nov-12',20],['03-Nov-12',20],['04-Nov-12',20],['05-Nov-12',20],['06-Nov-12',20],['07-Nov-12',20],['08-Nov-12',20],['09-Nov-12',20],['10-Nov-12',20],['12-Nov-12',0],['13-Nov-12',0],['14-Nov-12',0],['15-Nov-12',0],['16-Nov-12',0],['17-Nov-12',0],['18-Nov-12',0],['19-Nov-12',0],['20-Nov-12',0],['21-Nov-12',0],['22-Nov-12',0],['23-Nov-12',0],['24-Nov-12',0]];

  var plot2 = $.jqplot('openCloseChart', [line1, line2], {
    title:'Opened/Closed Complaints Chart',
    axes:{
      xaxis:{
        renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
          tickOptions:{
            formatString:'%b&nbsp;%#d'
          }
      },
      yaxis:{
        min:0,
        tickOptions:{
          formatString:'%d'
        }
      }
    },
    highlighter: {
      show: true
    },
    cursor: {
      show: false,
      tooltipLocation:'sw'
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        location: 'e',
        placement: 'outside',
        labels:['Opened', 'Closed']
    }
  });
});
```

I have created the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/tBZbf/5/

Can I get the graph to start on the first data point and finish on the last date dynamically? in this example 1rst of November and finish on the 24th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  xaxis:{
    min:'01-Nov-12',
    max:'24-Nov-12',
  },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QpjXd/

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify bit. This works great but I would like to do it dynamically without and not with fixed dates. Ideally I want jqplot to start the first point on the lowest date and finish on the highest.

Comment: Try to using hooks before initialisation, find max and min values in array and then add them to x axes.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I was wondering whether there was a simple option for this. Anyway it works with the hooks!

Answer (score 0):

A more complete answer can be found here:
[Why does jQPlot dateAxisRenderer not working correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891672/why-does-jqplot-dateaxisrenderer-not-working-correct)

(It just explains better how to add the hooks).